# Decrypt Flash SSL SSLKEYLOGFILE

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, flash, ssl, encryption

I was finding a way to decrypt SSL connection from a flash application (.swf). While reading and learning more about SSL and the way it encrypts and decrypts data I stumbled upon this website: https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Psst+Your+Browser+Knows+All+Your+Secrets+/16415

I am wondering if this file also stores the RSA key of the Flash ( AS3 ) websocket ? Or only communication in Firefox/Chrome?

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place to ask for help with breaking encryptions.

Comment: Why not ? It is a programming and general knowledge question. A lot of similar questions are asked here.